# Using a oauth token in second request - NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, oauth

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am trying to solve a problem that has bugged me pretty much for a few weeks now on and off (tried to solve it myself) and i am pretty stuck.

Basically i have a scenario where i am sending a data call to a identity server (Oauth 2.0) to retrieve a token that is then used in a API call.

To do this, i have setup two calls to the request module in NodeJS. The first call queries the server whilst the second call needs to use the token retrieved in the first to access the API i am accessing.

I cannot figure out how to get the variable from the first call (the token) to be accessible to the second request. I keep getting that it is undefined from the console.

This is the code i have tried so far. Relevant variable. Trying to take variable token through to request 2 as i need that token for the api call. I am running these requests in a function called dostuff.

```
 var request = require('request');
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var options = {
    url: 'https://identitywebsite.com/connect/token',
    headers: {'authorization' : 'basic <<KEY>>', 'Content-Type' :    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    port: '443',
    path: '/users',
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'grant_type=password&username=<<USERNAME>>&password=<<PASSWORD>>&scope=read+write'


var dostuff = function() {

request(options, function(error, response, body){

    console.log("success");
    Data = JSON.parse(body);
    //console.log(xx);
    global.token = data.access_token;

})

};

var options2 = {

    url: 'https://apiwebsite.com',
    headers: {'authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
    port: '443',
    path: '/users',
    method: 'GET'

}

console.log(options2);

request(options2, function(error, response, apiresponse){
console.log("triggered");
    console.log(" data success2");
    apidata = JSON.parse(apiresponse);  
    console.log(apidata);   

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a few things you should do.  One is use some promises.  Also do your best to not use global variables.

Also you are missing a closing bracket on your first options.

Promises are really neat though, as you can do things like this.

```
do_something(options)
          .then(function(my_data){
                   var options2 = {
                         url: 'https://apiwebsite.com',
                         headers: {'authorization' : 'Bearer ' + my_data, 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                         port: '443',
                         path: '/users',
                         method: 'GET'
                         }
                  do_something_else(options2)
                                 .then(function(my_other_data){
                                           //do stuff with my_other_data
                                            }
                }
```

Use this library!  It makes doing promises with requests really easy!

https://github.com/request/request-promise, you could also do this in bluebird which is my favorite of all the promise libraries, but it is slightly more complex.

Edit:

Since someone posted that this is off topic, which it isn't.  I will go farther in depth of why this is not working the way you think it should.  One of the reasons this is not working quite right is Node.JS is asynchronous.

What this means is your code is not waiting for your first request to finish before running your second request so you are not actually getting the token before your next request needs this.

One of the ways around this is to use promises like I said originally.  There are plenty of libraries out there that force synchronicity.  There is this library for example:

https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait

and many many more.

You could abstract this farther and call your first request from your second request as well to grab the API key and store it.

Comment: answer is very much off topic. please leave this as a comment instead.

Comment: My answer was perfectly fine but I added on to it.